# best way to call Laravel Auth helper method

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

i have a simple user table

```
-id
-name
-email
-role
```

should i use the first or the second method ?!

**the first method**

**1.**

```
if(auth()->user()->role == 'admin')
{
   // do something
}
else if (auth()->user()->role == 'supervised')
{
  // do something
}
else{
  //this is a simple user
}
```

**and this is the second method**

**2.**

```
$auth = auth()->user();
if($user->role == 'admin')
{
   // do something
}
else if ($user->role == 'supervised')
{
  // do something
}
else{
  //this is a simple user
}
```

does this method `auth()->user()` call the database each time i call it !!!?

Comment: @MRanaHossain can you tell me why the second one better ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make multiple calls when you use `auth()->user()` or relationships (it is loaded/set). You may install [clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) and check it.

Still, I wouldn't make these comparisons outside of the User class. Add these methods to your user model.

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->role === 'admin';
}

public function isSupervised()
{
    return $this->role === 'supervised';
}
```

and use them like;

```
auth()->user()->isAdmin()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer .

did you try to update the current user in auth()

if you for example update the name after the page reload you will find that the user is automatically selected from the database

Comment: @KokoMonsef after the update it didn't make a new request(probably setting the value in the class and returning from it). But if you `auth()->user()->refresh()` do that then it will make a new request to the database.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the first method instead of creating an unneccesary variable. It won't make multiple calls to the database. Check out the `user()` method in `SessionGaurd.php`

```
// If we've already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
// return it back immediately. We do not want to fetch the user data on
// every call to this method because that would be tremendously slow.
if (! is_null($this->user)) {
    return $this->user;
}
```